# When to save the state tree?

Tags: redux

The Redux manual says every reducer should be a pure function and even no API call should be made, I then curious to know, then, when should I get chance to save my App state tree to an external storage or the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your redux store using and action with the [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware.

Lets say you want to want to save the store when the user clicks save. First, define an action to do the save:

**actions/save.js**
    import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

```
export const save = state => {
    return () => {
        fetch('/api/path/to/save', {
            body: JSON.stringify(state), 
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
            method: 'POST'
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your component:

**components/SaveButton.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { save } from '../actions/save'

const SaveButton = props => {
    let { onSave, state } = props

    return <button onClick={onSave(state)}>Save</button>
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {state}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onSave: state => dispatch(save(state))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SaveButton)
```

Comment: Thanks.   From your example, it seems that the save action is not a normal object like {type, data} as that introduced in Redux Basic, it is a function in your code, right?  If so, what does the related reducer look like?

Comment: That's correct. This is how Redux Thunk works. Instead of returning an object, you return a function which the thunk middleware will call. There is no reducer for this, though you can add actions/reducers to change state indicating that saving is in progress or is finished. Check out the Redux Thunk docs for more info: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: From the documentation: "Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return a function instead of an action. The thunk can be used to delay the dispatch of an action, or to dispatch only if a certain condition is met. The inner function receives the store methods dispatch and getState as parameters."

Comment: Many thanks for the introducing to the Thunk.  I should read more :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that as part of your reducer.

Instead, whenever you want to save some part of your state, you should dispatch an asynchronous action (with the help of middleware like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)) perhaps called `SAVE_XYZ` with it's payload being the part of the store you want to save.

```
dispatch(saveXYZ(data))
```

`saveXYZ` needs to be an [async action creator](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators) that will dispatch the API call to persist your data, and handle the response accordingly.

```
const saveXYZ = payload => dispatch => {
    dispatch(saveXYZPending());
    return apiCallToStore(...)
             .then(data => saveXYZDone())
             .catch(err => saveXYZError());
}
```

You can read more on [async actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) and how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

Two basic approaches:

- Use `store.subscribe(callback)`, and write a callback that gets the latest state and persists it after some action has been dispatched
- Write a middleware that persists the state when some condition is met

There's [dozens of existing Redux store persistence libraries available](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store-persistence.md) that will do this work for you.